# Select previous record from row

Tags: mysql, sql

Example

```
id |u_id
 1 |  1 
 2 |  1 
 3 |  2 
 4 |  1 
 5 |  2 
 6 |  3
```

I know, the `id` 4 has `u_id` of 1, but I want to select the last row having `u_id` 1 before that with `id` 4 i.e. I want to select the row with the `id` 2.

Note that I don't know this `id`.

How can I achieve that?

This is what the result should look like:

```
id |u_id 
 2 |  1
 4 |  1
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you know the id (4) or the u_id (1). Note that the former is more probable.

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the correct sql query for it.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE u_id = 1 AND (id = 4 OR id < 4) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: While that gives you the rows you are looking for exactly, hardcoding the `u_id = 1`, please take a look at my answer where you do not need to know the value of `u_id` that comes before the `2`.

Comment: I tried to run your query but it flagged it as a wrong query. I don't know why.

Comment: My query uses `example` as the table name. You can change it to your own table name if you need to. Did you run the DEMO?

Comment: yes i did and i got some errors i didn't know how to fix

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where uid=1 order by id desc limit 2
```

Comment: The u_id = 1 will restrict the result to just one row. The `order by id desc` part of the query will become redundant.

Comment: that's not correct, based on your sample data, u_id=1 will return (1,1), (2,1) and (4,1), order by id desc is used to select the top 2 largest id which is (2,1) and (4,1)

Comment: my bad. i saw it as id instead of u_id. let me try it and see what happens. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
 SELECT * FROM ( SELECT  * FROM yourTable WHERE u_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) AS tab ORDER BY tab.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

As your title states:

> select previous record from row

The following gives you every row that comes ***prior*** to a `2`, and will work with more than just the data you've shown in your example:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id - 1
    FROM example
    WHERE u_id = 2);
```

[image]

[[SEE DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/BZBC72070)

Comment: `id - 1` is not part of the request

Comment: @Strawberry I hear you. Honestly I should have just flagged this question as unclear and moved on. It’s likely the reason there are many answers, some of which don’t solve much of a puzzle (using ‘LIMIT’ to filter out the edge cases). With the title as it is, a future visitor might benefit from my simple approach if they have a problem to solve that lands them on this exact Q&A page. Remains to be seen if the OP ever picks a correct answer (since they’ve posted the answer to their own question and didn’t mark it either <shrugs>).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fairly recent version of MySQL, what you need is the LAG() windowed function:

```
SELECT  id,
        u_id,
        LAG(id) OVER W AS prev_id
FROM MyTable
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY id)
ORDER BY id, u_id;
```

It will produce a result like this:

```
id |u_id |prev_id
 1 |  1  | null
 2 |  1  |  1
 3 |  2  | null
 4 |  1  |  2
 5 |  2  |  3
 6 |  3  | null
```

You can play with the query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rCwxosPNu5ymBDV43SwHah/0).